# Passing params to $resource query or get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-resource, angularjs-factory

I am trying to pass some params to a resource call to get only the votes matching those params

It seems to be ignoring those params on a query because it just returns all of the votes regardless of params

Also when attempting to use get like this post suggests: [Angular 1.0.8 $resource with multiple optional get parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247563/angular-1-0-8-resource-with-multiple-optional-get-parameters) it gives error: expected object but got an array

What is the issue here?

Service

```
 wrmcServices.factory 'Vote', ($resource) ->
   $resource 'api/v1/votes.json',{},
     query:
       method:'GET'
       params:
         voteId:'votes'
       isArray:true
```

Note: I also tried removing the params: voteId:'votes' but it made no difference, if anyone wants to tell me what this does in this case it would be good to know, i just added that part from a tutorial

My query and get attempts

```
Vote.query({votable_id:scope.votableId,votable_type:scope.votableType});
Vote.get({votable_id:scope.votableId,votable_type:scope.votableType});
```

Comment: perhaps something like this: $resource 'api/v1/votes.json', {votable_id: '@votable_id', votable_type: '@votable_type'}, ...

Comment: But this will be used in other cases too, i shouldnt have to specify any and all parameters that i could possibly be using in the service. And that doesnt work anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, the working code is as follows:

```
var $scope.vote;
Vote.get({votable_id:scope.votableId,votable_type:scope.votableType}, function (result){
  $scope.vote = result
});
```

or

```
var $scope.votes;
Vote.query({votable_id:scope.votableId,votable_type:scope.votableType}, function (result){
  $scope.votes = result
});
```